# Angular Populate dropdown options dynamically while selecting dropdown in runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select

I have a JSON object containing names of dropdown and looks something like this -

```
$scope.obj = { 
    "dp1" :{},
    "dp2" :{}
}
```

Objects `dp1` and `dp2` correspond to respective dropdowns. These objects will be referred by dropdown to populate their `options` tag.
Next I have a REST call function like this -

```
$scope.getData = function(category, type) {
    var params = { "dp1" : category, "dp1__type": type};
    PromiseService.getPromiseData("GET", "/api/get_data/?" + $httpParamSerializer(params)).then(function(response) {
        $scope.obj.dp1= response;
    });
}
```

I am able to assign the response to `$scope.obj.dp1` 
 The reponse object looks like this-

```
{ "id" : 1, "name" : "john" }
```

Finally, my dropdown looks like this -

```
<select id="d1" ng-model="d1">
    <option ng-repeat="opt in obj.dp1" t>{{opt.id}}_{{opt.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I want to populate the `obj` JSON object based on response, which I able to. Then I want to go to sub object in `obj` and apply `ng-repeat` on that to populate the `options` tag.

Current implementation of `ng-repeat` gives me `undefined undefined` .

Comment: use the ng-option directive its exactly for this purpose to avoid using ng-repeat documentation here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: `<option ng-repeat="opt in obj.dp1" ng-value='opt.id'>{{opt.id}}_{{opt.name}}</option>`

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
$scope.obj = {

    "dropdown1" :{id:"dp2", data:"", options:[]},
    "dropdown2":{id:"dp1", data:"", options:[]}
}

$scope.getData = function(category, type){
           var params = { "dp1" : category, "dp1__type": type};
           PromiseService.getPromiseData("GET", "/api/get_data/?" + $httpParamSerializer(params)).then(function(response){
                    $scope.obj.dropdown1.options = response;
           });
       }
```

html page -

```
<div ng-repeat="dropdown in obj">
   <select id="{{dropdown.id}}" ng-model="dropdown.data" ng-options="option.name for option in dropdown.options">
</div>
```